# Using custom workspace in Jenkins causes git timeout

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to checkout, and build my git project in a custom folder using Jenkins. I have set the custom workspace from the "Advance Project Options" tab. However, whenever I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
Building in workspace /myapp
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/.../... # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
> git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
> git reset --hard # timeout=10
> git clean -fdx # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

But if I run the project in the default workspace, it seems to work fine.

I'm wondering whether the structure of my custom workspace is wrong. Basically, I have the following setup:

The name of my git repo is "myapp". When I use the defualt workspace, the project is checked out, and built in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace/[files inside myapp repo]. After this, I have to copy the files from the default workspace to my actual folder using:

```
cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace/* /myapp/.
```

But for the custom workspace, I have given the directory as /myapp. I want Jenkins to checkout the code from git into /myapp, and then do the build. Would the folder structure cause any problems? If not, why is it failing?

Comment: Some pointers? Anyone?